Quotient topology after Gluing
Question: Let $X = ([0,2] \times \{0\}) \cup ([0,2]\times \{1\})$ and let $Y$ be the space obtained from gluing each $t$ in the first copy of the interval to the corresponding second copy of the interval for all $t\in [0,2]$ except $t=1$. Explicitly, $Y$ is the quotient of $X$ by the relation which glues $(t,0)$ to $(t,1)$ for all $t\in [0,2]\setminus{1}$. Let $Y$ have the quotient topology.

Show that $Y$ is not Hausdorff.

Im struggling to understand the quotient topology in general. I know that in this case, we can view $Y$ as being two line segments with two dots at the points $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ because we didnt glue those points.
I know that the open sets in $Y$ are the sets such that $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $Y$ where $\pi$ is the map that sends $(x,y)\in X$ to its equivalence class in $Y = X/R$, but what do open sets 'look like' in that case? How do I determine which sets in $Y$ are open? And how do I then formally show that there are no disjoint opens around a pair of points in $X$?
Edit: Any neighborhood of $(1,1)$ in $Y$ contains points of the form $(t,1)$ for $t \in (1-\epsilon,1) \cup (1,1+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon>0$ small. Similarly for $(1,0)$ we have that any neighborhood of it must contain points of the form $(t,0)$ for $t \in (1-\epsilon,1) \cup (1,1+\epsilon)$. Then notice that $\pi((t,0)) = \pi((t,1))$.
Since the images of the neighborhoods of $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ always intersect,
the space is not Hausdorff.

This is basically a question about the line with two origins. The space here is slightly different but the idea is exactly the same

"but what do open sets 'look like' in that case? How do I determine which sets in Y are open? And how do I then formally show that there are no disjoint opens around a pair of points in X?" answer to all of those questions is in the property you already listed, that $V\subseteq Y$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is an open set.

Hint: What are the open sets in the case that you glue all points, not leaving out 1?

@BenSteffan If you were to glue all the points then we'd get just the interval $[0,2]$ and then the inverse images of an open interval on this interval would result in a union of two of those open intervals in $X$ (which is open in $X$), so open intervals, (and unions and intersections of these) would be open in $Y$.

@BenSteffan But then I don't really understand what happens if we don't glue the two middle points. What changes in this situation with the opens?

@want2know make a case distinction: take $(1 - \epsilon, 1), (1, 1 + \epsilon) \subset X$ and work out what happens if you add in $1_1, 1_2$ (the two distinct copies of 1 in that space), or both. Is the result still open?

@BenSteffan I've edited the post to include what i've currently got after reading your comment. Is this what you had in mind?
